# How to create db_select query from simple sql query

Tags: drupal-7

I have a sql query as:

```
SELECT `entity_type` FROM `field_data_field_project_team_member` WHERE field_project_team_member_uid=30
```

and i want it to write in a db_select().
How to write it in db_select ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go through various tutorials and found drupal formate to write a query for it as:

```
$sub_qry = db_select('field_data_field_project_team_member', 't');
$sub_qry->fields('t', array('entity_id'));
$sub_qry->where("t.field_project_team_member_uid = 30");
```

Hope its useful for someone else.